# npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint

Tags: node.js, angular

**when i run ng new it shows**

> \ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has
> been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see
> https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
>
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node
> v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node
> v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
>
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see
> https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
>
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1:
> https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
>
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
> '...-grunt-tasks":"^4.0.0'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Abitech\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-02T16_28_06_793Z-debug.log

× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Answer (score 7):

1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
3. npm install -g @angular/cli
4. ng new projectName

This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

i had the exact same error so i followed these steps and then i was able to create a new project successfully

1) Run ( Win + R ) then type %AppData% , then clear the npm-cache folder , i.e delete that folder manually.
2) Then again run the command ng new project name

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

npm cache verify

npm install npm@latest -g

Then:

ng new projectName

Answer (score 1):

> **(...) TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint.**

If `npm update tslint` didn't help, you can install and use `eslint` instead.

Url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Comment: Dear @Julian please don't ask a question in the answer.

Comment: Dear @CyberEternal, okay - fixed it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1.Run npm cache clean --force
2.Manually delete npm and npm-cache folders from AppData/Roaming folder (Win + R, Type %AppData% and enter)
3.Run Node Installer and repair
4.Reinstall npm install -g @angular/cli
5.Rerun ng new newApp
Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete npm-cache folder in `'C:\Users\User Name \AppData\Roaming'`
and recreate project